# List all child node from parent node in a TreeView in C#

Tags: c#, treeview

TreeView:

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

Hi, I have a problem regarding to the tree view. I was trying to have a list of output like above picture but Im not really know how to do it. Im really appreaciate for your help, tq.

Comment: Is this WinForms? Can the nodes go deeper than one level? If the root node has no children, then you just output the text of the root node?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which direction you're going.  I interpreted this as going from the TreeView to something else (TextBox maybe?).

If so, this could be as simple as:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<String> output = new List<string>();
    output.Add("Activity List:");
    foreach(TreeNode tn in treeView1.Nodes)
    {
        if (tn.Nodes.Count == 0)
        {
            output.Add(tn.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach(TreeNode child in tn.Nodes)
            {
                output.Add(child.Text);
            }
        }
    }
    textBox1.Lines = output.ToArray();
}
```

Output:

[image]